# Get current frame of playing video in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a combination of [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) and [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) packages in flutter to play a video in my app.

The documentation does not tell anything about video frames, so I was wondering if anyone has a method to get the current playing frame on a playing video. Or if that is even possible.

Comment: Not sure if you can do this but there is a way to take a screenshot of the widget, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117958/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-current-widget-flutter this might help as a work around

Comment: Do you mean an `Image` or an `int`? Either way, I think that you should [file an issue for `video_player`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=[video_player]%20%3CTitle%20here%3E) because it does not expose it at the moment.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I wanted to get the frame number, so probably an int, however, as you mentioned, this is not exposed at the time of this writing...so I had to make some maths to...more or less....get the frame number.....good enough if no other better solution available.