# How take a picture automatic after 3 seconds in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a punch clock in a tablet with Flutter Application and I need this functionality.

I know how to make the camera show and the user make a screenshot, but I searched everywhere how to make an automatic self screenshot after 3 seconds and don't find anything.

Someone has an example, tutorial, or experience to make something like this?

Comment: did you take a look at the [Timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html) class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timer class to do some action after certain time duration as shown below

```
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () {
    //after 3 seconds this will be called, 
    //once this is called take picture or whatever function you need to do
    takeScreenshot();
  });
```

And if you want,use this code below to take screenshot as mentioned in this answer [Take Screenshot Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118088/12257758)

```
takeScreenShot() async{
   RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = 
      previewContainer.currentContext.findRenderObject();
   ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
   final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
   ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
   Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
   print(pngBytes);
   File imgFile =new File('$directory/screenshot.png');
   imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
  }
```

Hope this helps!