# flutter: taking screenshots of a widget from its sibling

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, state, hierarchy

### Goal

I have a view that has two children Widget A and Widget B, standing side by side. Widget B has a button that triggers a screenshot on Widget A,

### Problem

but referring to questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117958/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-current-widget-flutter/51118088#51118088), it seems that the implementation of screen capture must stay within Widget A. So the button callback in Widget B needs to talk to Widget A. Since both are stateful widgets, I find it difficult for B to call A's function inside its state.

The various provider and inheritedWidget mechanisms seem to handle parent-to-child state propagation nicely but it's unclear to me how to handle siblings.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can call `someGlobalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject()` from any place in the tree, no need for doing that from the child widget

Comment: @pskink Thanks. Indeed, I forgot I could use global key as a static var!

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question as per @pskink 's tip:

Just use `GlobalKey` as a globally accessible variable such as a static member of Widget A, then we could refer to A's context anywhere in the tree.