# Need to record specific portion of screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video-capture, video-recording

Currently, I'm using a flutter screen recorder plugin(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screen_recording) to record the screen, Actually, this plugin records the full screen of the mobile.
But my requirement is to record only a particular widget or a particular section of the screen, For example in the duet video recording  there button to start recording in the screen, I just want to record only the duet video recording.
So Is there any  solution available for this, Please guide.

Comment: Not the exact same but you could check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63049828/flutter-taking-screenshots-of-a-widget-from-its-sibling/63050513#63050513) for help.

Comment: I have already implemented but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

screen_recorder: ^0.0.2 can be used to record specific portion of screen