Entire screenshot for Android and iOS
I want to capture screenshot for entire screen of android and iOS devices. But I couldn't find any solution.
I have tried some packages, "screenshot, screen_capturer,native_screenshot, native_screenshot_ext" which didn't worked to capture a screenshot on android or iOS.
"screen_capturer" allows to capture entire screen but only for MAC, WEB and DESKTOP.
"screen_capturer", and "native_screenshot_ext" aren't compatible for newer versions. Also there is no update since 2 years in these packages.
"screenshot" only captures flutter widgets.

try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66126404/14071053

this isn't helpful in that thread we are discussing the same thing which is unsolved.

Try using AngryAndroid/flutter_screenshot_callback in your project to detect the screenshot captured by system (still invoked by user hand, instead of your codes, such as pressing physical button, pressing virtual capture button on both platform and capture gesture on Android) in order that you can save it to the storage or share to other apps. 
Any questions for this plugin on Android are welcomed.

But it would not capture the screenshot.

I will post the codes later, please stay tuned.

I have posted my code and may it will help.

Where I can find the code
