# How to save a screen with overlapping images and text as a jpg in Flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

The gray screen is an image and the user can write any text on it.

And I want to convert the image and text overlapping on the final screen to jpg, but I don't know how.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118088/13625293

Comment: Take a screenshot of the page using https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot and use it where_ever you want